# How do i change button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that slides down a div showing some content. 
How can I do to change the text in the button when the div is open. It has to change from "VER MÁS" to "VER MENOS"

```
<a id="showfoo" class="btn btn-primary hidden-xs">VER MÁS</a>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showfoo').click(function() {
            $('#foo').slideToggle(1000, "swing");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/text

Answer (score 1):

you can use the ternary operator and .text() to achieve this.

```js
$(function() {
   
   $('#showfoo').click(function() {
       $('#foo').slideToggle(1000, "swing");
       var txt = $(this).text() == "VER MÁS" ? "VER MENOS" : "VER MÁS";
       $(this).text(txt);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showfoo" class="btn btn-primary hidden-xs">VER MÁS</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(function() {
   
   $('#showfoo').click(function() {
       $('#foo').slideToggle(1000, "swing");
        $(this).toggleClass('showHide');
        if($(this).hasClass('showHide')) {
         $(this).text('Show');
        } else {
         $(this).text('Hide');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showfoo" class="btn btn-primary hidden-xs showHide">Show</button>
```

Hope this helps!